# Jest async tests time out when used with mongodb-memory-server

Tags: mongodb, jestjs, integration-testing

I have an Express app that I'm trying to test with Jest and supertest.

So in the below code, I have 2 test cases:

1. Given the correct sign-up data, it should create and return the new user
2. Given the email that is already registered, it should respond with a 409 Conflict error

**users.test.ts:**

```
import requests from "supertest";
import { MongoMemoryServer } from "mongodb-memory-server";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import createServer from "../utils/createServer";
import User from "../models/User";
import { getRandomProfilePath } from "../utils/pathsGenerators";
const app = createServer();

let mongod: MongoMemoryServer;

beforeAll(async () => {
  mongod = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
  mongoose.connect(mongod.getUri());
});

afterAll(async () => {
  await mongoose.disconnect();
  await mongoose.connection.close();
  await mongod.stop();
});

const signUpData = {
  firstName: "john",
  lastName: "doe",
  email: "johndoe@gmail.com",
  password: "1234567890"
};

const userDataForModel = {
  ...signUpData,
  profilePath: getRandomProfilePath()
}

describe("auth", () => {
  describe("sign-up", () => {
    describe("given all correct sign-up data", () => {
      // this works as expected
      it("returns created user and token", async () => {
        const { body, statusCode, headers } = await requests(app)
          .post("/auth/sign-up")
          .send(signUpData);

          expect(headers["content-type"]).toMatch(/json/);
          expect(statusCode).toBe(201);
          expect(body.user).toBeDefined();
          expect(body.token).toBeDefined();
      })
    })

    describe("given user already exists", () => {
      it("returns 409", async () => {
        // times out after this line
        await User.create(userDataForModel);

        // everything below doesn't seem to be reached
        const { statusCode, body } = await requests(app)
          .post("/auth/sign-up")
          .send(signUpData)

        console.log(statusCode);
        console.log(body);

        expect(statusCode).toBe(409);
        expect(body.message).toBeDefined();
      })
    })
  })
})
```

The problem is that the second test case always times out after calling `await User.create(userDataForModel)`. I think this may be because the app isn't actually running when `User.create()` is called , but I could be wrong.

I see that `User.create()` actually sends a successful HTTP request as the following appears in the console:

`::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [15/Apr/2023:16:15:33 +0000] "POST /auth/sign-up HTTP/1.1" 201 700`

**What I have tried**:

1. using `await requests(app)...` instead of `User.create(userDataForModel)`
2. using axios
3. using `beforeAll()` and `afterAll()` instead of `beforeEach()` and `afterEach()`
4. importing the app from `index.ts` file, rather than creating a separate instance by using `createServer()`
5. using `.then()` instead of `async/await`
6. Increasing the timeout limit

**createServer.ts**:

```
import express from "express";
import allRoutes from "../routes/index";
import globalMiddleware from "../middleware/globalMiddleware";
import notFound from "../middleware/notFound";
import errHandler from "../middleware/errHandler";

export default function createServer() {
  const app = express();

  app.use(globalMiddleware);
  app.use(allRoutes);
  app.use(notFound);
  app.use(errHandler);

  return app;
}
```

**index.ts**:

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
import "express-async-errors";
import connectDB from "./utils/connectDB";
import createServer from "./utils/createServer";
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const app = createServer();

app.listen(PORT, async () => {
  console.log(`app running on port ${PORT}`);
  await connectDB();
  console.log("DB connected");
})

export default app;
```

The issue seems to always come from `await User.create(userDataForModel)`. I tried running it inside the first test, and it makes it timeout too.

In essence, I'm looking for a way to create data in the DB before running `requests(app)`. I heard some things about `jest.fn()` and `jest.mock()`, but not sure how this is applicable here.